# Are run time structs possible in open MPI?

Tags: java, c, openmpi

I'm trying to create a custom data type (which I call `AttribStruct`)  using Open MPI's Java bindings, but I'm getting a `invalid datatype` error when I try to run the program. I suspect it's because the dimensions of the arrays within the structs are determined at run time.

My goal is to send n `AttribStruct` buffers in each `send` and `recv` operation. So, I concatenate all `n` individual buffers into one big buffer in order to send them all together. Then the receiving end deconstructs the buffers.

Below is the AttribStruct class

```java
public class AttribStruct extends Struct {

    // Pointers to  the objectives, variables, and constraints
    private final int objectives;
    private final int variables;
    private final int constraints;

    // an int that represents a boolean for whether the objectives are valid (1 true, 0 false)
    private final int validObjectiveFunctionsValues;
    private final int validConstraintsViolationValues;

    public final int objCount;
    public final int varCount;
    public final int constrCount;

    public AttribStruct(int objCount, int varCount, int constrCount) {
        this.objCount = objCount;
        this.varCount = varCount;
        this.constrCount = constrCount;
        this.objectives = addDouble(this.objCount);
        this.constraints = addDouble(this.constrCount);
        this.variables = addDouble(this.varCount);

        this.validObjectiveFunctionsValues = addInt();
        this.validConstraintsViolationValues = addInt();

    }

    @Override
    protected Data newData() {
        return new Data();
    }

    public class Data extends Struct.Data {

        /*
         * Getters go here
         */


        /*
         * Setters go here
         */

    } // End -- Data

}
```

And below is an example of me sending a number of structs:

```
AttribStruct attr = new AttribStruct(4, 3, 0);
/*
 * Build buffer goes here
 */
attr.getType().commit();
MPI.COMM_WORLD.iSend(toSend, n, attr.getType(), target, 0);
attr.getType().free();
```

Where `toSend` is `n` different AttribStruct buffers concatenated together, `n` is the number of attribs structs I'm sending, `attr` is an instance of the AttribStruct class, `target` is the rank of the node I'm communicating with, and `0` is just a place holder.

And below is a rough example of the target node receiving the message:

```
AttribStruct attr = new AttribStruct(4, 3, 0);
attr.getType().commit();
MPI.COMM_WORLD.recv(msgBuffer, n, attr.getType(), MASTER_RANK, 0);
attr.getType().free();
/*
 * Deconstruct buffer goes here
 */
```

However, when I run the program, I get the following error messages:

```
[node01:13219] *** An error occurred in MPI_Recv
[node01:13219] *** reported by process [203161601,0]
[node01:13219] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[node01:13219] *** MPI_ERR_TYPE: invalid datatype
[node01:13219] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[node01:13219] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

Does my overall strategy make sense? If so, can you help me figure out what I'm doing incorrectly? Let me know if you want further details, since I omitted some code to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be looking for `MPI_Type_create_struct`: https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Type_create_struct.html.  See previous questions and answers like:

- [MPI create MPI_Datatype from struct containing structs with structs and typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892788/mpi-create-mpi-datatype-from-struct-containing-structs-with-structs-and-typedef)
- [Using MPI_Type_create_struct() to transfer structs containing dynamic arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225554/using-mpi-type-create-struct-to-transfer-structs-containing-dynamic-arrays-in)